# Payment forms fail with "Unknown api version"

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment, drupal-7

Seemingly after updating CiviCRM to 5.50.3 and webform_civicrm to 7.x-5.8 on drupal 7.83, webform payments fail. Watchdog says

```
The CiviCRM "contribution transact" API returned the error: "Unknown api version" 
when called by function "validate" on line 97 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc 
with parameters: "Array ( [credit_card_type] => MasterCard [credit_card_number] => xxxxxxxxxx...[snip]
[form_token] => qnqM4nlUWJSVIPZiCsb57jdigsIZ76jGiG0Aa9a6nyc [form_id] => 
webform_client_form_2556 [op] => Submit [payment_instrument_id] => 1 [payment_processor] 
=> 5 [card_type_id] => 2 [pan_truncation] => 7947 [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 )
```

As a result, it appears everything to be handled after payment is not done, storing the payment in civicrm, sending mails/invoices, adding contacts to groups, etc - however, strangely, the payment seems to have been done.

Assuming this string "Unknown api version" comes from Civi/API/Request.php,
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/fb87724ca7f9fd42560e0729e9e46a3c...

it seems `$params['version']` is not 3 or 4.

It is clear in the error message version is either 3 or '3' - I can't see where the value comes from in `function contributionParams` - if it comes from a post, it might be a string?

@see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3294171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have https://civicrm.org/extensions/contribution-transact-api installed? You need that now if using webform with contributions.

Comment: Thanks os much ! How could I have known ?! yes, that changes the error. I am testing on a development server, and not sure if all my settings are right. it now keeps telling me `It appears that this transaction is a duplicate` even when using different amounts. Do you know if there is anything else I need to configure to have `wf_civicrm` work with the `contribution-transact-api` ?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything else.

Comment: It has the same errors on live ..

Comment: @commonpike See if https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25020 fixes the "transaction is a duplicate" issue?